# How i can bind StaticResource key in View model

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have different ControlTemplates for one Canvas:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Control1" />
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Control2" />
</Application.Resources>
```

I want to change one of them by my viewmodel property like this:

```
private string _template = "Control1";
public string Template
        {
            get
            {
                return _template;
            }
            set
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                {
                    _template = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Template");
                }
            }
        }
```

And finally use it in my view:

```
<UserControl Template="{StaticResource {Binding Template}}" />
```

But it doesn't work, how i can fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using DataTriggers

```
<UserControl>
<UserControl.Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type UserControl}">
<Setter Property="ControlTemplate" value="{StaticResource Control1}"/>
<Style.Triggers>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Template}" Value ="Control1">
<Setter Property="ControlTemplate" value="{StaticResource Control1}"/>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Template}" Value ="Control2">
<Setter Property="ControlTemplate" value="{StaticResource Control2}"/>
</DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</UserControl.Style>
</UserControl>
```